# How to reference an instance of another class?

Tags: java

sorry for the stupid question but I really cant solve it myself and can't find a fitting solution.

I have multiple classes: MusicCollection,Albums and Songs. In each is an ArrayList and a bunch of methods to store new albums via a GUI class. Now I built anoter class Playlist with a LinkedList that should be able to get songs from albums .

In the GUI class I create an instance of MusicCollection to add albums and songs and use the methods of these classes.

To add songs to the playlist I create an instance of Playlist in the GUI class. This instance of Playlist needs to have access to the instance of MusicCollection to get its songs. How can I solve this? I tried to make the instance of the MusicCollection public, didn't work, I tried to call it over the getter, didn't work either.

If I make a new instance of MusicCollection within the PlayList Class it's empty of course :-/

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: some code you've tried so far?

Comment: The most intresting part should be the findSong() method at line 23.

Comment: Va, err, a reference? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: There is no error. If I try to use the ArrayList myCollection as public within the Playlist class intelliJ wont find the reference, If create another instance of MusicCollection  within the Playlist Class the debugger tells me it's empty. How do  get access to MusicCollection myCollection from within the Playlist Class?

Comment: DO NOT PASTE LINKS TO EXTERNAL SOURCES. PASTE THE CODE ITSELF AS TEXT IN YOUR QUESTION (NOT IN COMMENTS).

Comment: Define "didn't work", "won't find the reference", etc.

Comment: progy_rock sry, didn't know about that.

@EJP In intelliJ it's just red and when I hover over it it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'myCollection'"

Comment: I might have to add that each class has it's own .java file. I don't know if that's relevant for the scope or something.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: If I try to call MusicCollection.getMyCollection I get the error "Non-static method 'getMyCollection()' cannot be referenced from a static  context.

Comment: Brandon, your Link didn't help at all. And in general: thx for the downvotes, really helps a beginner whos trying his best to get a valid solution or even a hint here. Guess that's why so few people get into coding.

Comment: So there is an error but it isn't an error?

Comment: The error must be logical. There is no clear error message. I just get a wrong output.  See code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you need to construct objects from class `ClassA` with references to **already existing** objects you must implement `ClassA` in such a way that those objects can be passed as argument to the constructor of `ClassA`. You can then in the constructor choose to save those objects as fields or choose to use them right away and don't save them (if you do not need them later on in `ClassA`).

```
public class ClassA {
    public ClassA(OtherClass1 obj1, OtherClass2 obj2){
         // do what you want with obj1 and obj2
    }
}
```

when you create a `ClassA` object:

```
OtherClass1 obj1 = ...;
OtherClass2 obj2 = ...;
// ...
ClassA aObj = new ClassA(obj1, obj2);
```

In your your code I see you've already defined a field so you know each `Playlist` object needs a `MusicCollection` object. The question is which `MusicCollection`-object? In your description it looks like you have to create that one outside the `Playlist` class. If you want that each `PlayList`-object has to be constructed based on an already existing `MusicCollection`-object, you'll need to apply the concept explained above. The constructor of `PlayList` will be:

```
public PlayList(MusicCollection collection){
    musicCollection = collection;
}
```

After that, the collection that had been given during the creation of the `PlayList` object can be accessed through the `musicCollection` field. So you just need to pass the right collection with the data you need as argument when you create a new `PlayList` object.

```
// Create a MusicCollection 
MusicCollection musicCollection = new MusicCollection();

// do things with that collection ... (fill it up for eg.)

// Create the playlist that will use that collection
PlayList playlist = new PlayList(musicCollection);
```

**EDIT:** there is an important mistake in your code I forgot to point out:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   private void addSongfromAlbum(){
       System.out.println("Please select a Song to add to the Playlist\n");
       String name = scanner.nextLine();
       playlist.addSongToPlaylist(name);
   }
}
```

You're creating the method `addSongfromAlbum` in another method: the `main` method. Creating a method in another method is not allowed.

Comment: Wow, faith in this page restored. I finally managed to get it done correctly now! And as for the edit: I know, just copy pasted some code together in a hurry. In the real thing it looks a bit different anyway ^^ 

I wish I could upvote, sadly I don't have enough reputation yet :-/ I really can't thank you enough :-)

Comment: My pleasure ;-)  no problem. I'm glad it helped